# Strict-Transport Header HSTS

Tags: http, tomcat

I need to configure the HSTS (HTTP Strict-Transport Header) in Linux. I have added the following on the Tomcat/Conf Web.xml file:
 
        httpHeaderSecurity
        org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter

```
    <init-param>
  <param-name>hstsEnabled</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>hstsMaxAgeSeconds</param-name>
  <param-value>31536000</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>hstsIncludeSubDomains</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
 <async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

I have also added port 80 on the server.xml file and I still cannot the Strict Transport Header.

Answer (score 0):

The HSTS is a security configuration for HTTPS sites and is not to be configured with plain HTTP, as you are doing.

See [Mozilla - Strict-Transport-Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security)

> The HTTP Strict-Transport-Security response header (often abbreviated
>   as HSTS)  lets a web site tell browsers that it should only be
>   accessed using HTTPS, instead of using HTTP.

As per the requirements of the [link](https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/hsts-for-tomcat/) in your comment, to have HSTS in Tomcat, you need to have a web server frontend, on the same host.

> In order to be accepted to the HSTS preload list through this form,
>   your site must satisfy the following set of requirements:
>
> - Serve a valid certificate.
> - Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on the same host, if you are listening on port 80.
> - Serve all subdomains over HTTPS.

Per our FAQ, it is off topic guiding you on the specific steps to do it.

A possible solution is to configure [Apache+SSL+a X.509 certificate as a front end for your site/Tomcat](https://serverfault.com/questions/505316/ssl-setup-with-apache-in-front-of-tomcat). Beware that when doing that, [there are also specific steps for Tomcat too](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl). See also the [tomcat 9 official SSL guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I used this link to configure it: https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/hsts-for-tomcat/   do you have something that I can look at to configure it?

Comment: While getting outside the realm of the question and getting into off-topic land, I added clarifications to the answer to guide you. Nevertheless, it is not an easy task to put https working, mind you. I advise getting professional consulting help for this first time or your local friendly fellow Unix sysadmin.